# Django Subquery Subset of Previous Records

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I am trying to annotate a queryset with an aggregate of a subset of previous rows. Take the following example table of a player's score in a particular game, with the column, *last_2_average_score* being the rolling average from the previous two games score for a particular player.

```
+----------+-----------+---------+-------------------------+
|   date   |    player |   score |    last_2_average_score |
+----------+-----------+---------+-------------------------+
| 12/01/19 |         1 |      10 |   None                  |
| 12/02/19 |         1 |       9 |    None                 |
| 12/03/19 |         1 |       8 |    9.5                  |
| 12/04/19 |         1 |       7 |    8.5                  |
| 12/05/19 |         1 |       6 |    7.5                  |
+----------+-----------+---------+-------------------------+
```

In order to accomplish this, i wrote the following query, trying to annotate each "row" with the corresponding 2 game average for their score

```
ScoreModel.objects.annotate(
    last_two_average_score=Subquery(
        ScoreModel.objects.filter(
            player=OuterRef("player"), date__lt=OuterRef("date")
        )
        .order_by("-date")[:2]
        .annotate(Avg("score"))
        .values("score__avg")[:1],
        output_field=FloatField(),
    )
)
```

This query however, does not output the correct result. In fact the result is just every record annotated with

```
{'last_two_average_score': None}
```

I have tried a variety of different combinations of the query, and cannot find the correct combination. Any advice that you can give would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to address the problem from the ORM first, I ended up circling back and first trying to implement the query in raw SQL. This immediately lead me to the concept of WINDOW functions, which when I looked in Django's ORM for, found very quickly.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions

For this interested, the resulting query looks something like this, which was much simpler than what I was trying to accomplish with Subquery

```
ScoreModel.objects.annotate(
    last_two_average=Window(
        expression=Avg("score"),
        partition_by=[F("player")],
        order_by=[F("date").desc()],
        frame=RowRange(start=-2, end=0),
    )
)
```